# How I do set Xcowsay on login without the cow disappearing?

Tags: command-line, startup-applications

I love xcowsay app. And I want that it starts on logon. I added to startup manager this command: `xcowsay Hi`.

But after login, the cow doesn't show, only the speech bubble. Although, when I type it on Terminal runs good. I don't know if it's because command, startup order or user  permission.

All startup applications with commands runs well. I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Xcowsay version 1.2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem that when we logon, the devices are not mounted except for the root device and home directory. Even sometimes, home directory fails to start. So application run normally which belongs to the path file `system/user/bin/` directory as an executable otherwise may cause problems even if it belongs to some other paths. Well try to check if you have checked it in the startup application window.
Also check if your file is listed here `Check ~/.config/autostart`. Try to add the application there and then it will run properly I suppose.

Comment: Actually, every partition/file system mentioned in `/etc/fstab` should be already mounted by the time you log in. If not, something is configured incorrectly.

Comment: then just look up if everything is correct with xconf file. and every enetry is made there correctly. will look over your problem tomorrow as I have to prepare for the exam i am having tomorrow

Comment: @ashutosh Thanks for the answer! I did these steps and now works! 
Also I realize that the app doesn't start very well on Gnome, but yes on Unity.